# MySQL: Select two values of two columns and compared their values exchanging them each other

Tags: mysql, select

I need to find a way to select one random row where the `subscriber` is not also `leader` (in the same or any other row).

Something like this: (just to have an idea)

```
SELECT `leader`,`subscriber` FROM `relations` WHERE `subscriber`.`leader` != `leader`.`subscriber` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

This is the table `relations`:

```
+---+--------+-----------+
| id| leader | subscriber|
+---+--------+-----------+
| 1 |       2|          5|
| 2 |       5|          2|
| 3 |       4|          8|
| 4 |       8|          4|
| 5 |       9|          6|
+---+--------+-----------+
```

So in this example is 9 and 6 (last row).

Is it possible to achieve this with just one query?

**UPDATE**

I noticed a long execute time for this query (about 40 secs)!

This is the output for my table `relations`:

```
| relations | CREATE TABLE `relations` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `leader` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `subscriber` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=35207 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
```

Comment: You first say *I need **all** subscribers* and then use `limit 1`, do you need **all** or **one**?

Comment: @Lamak I need to check all rows and then limit 1

Comment: checking all rows is very different than selecting all rows

Comment: @Lamak I need to select values `leader` and `subscriber` of only 1 row

Comment: So you want only one (random) subscriber that meets your criteria, not all of them, correct?

Comment: @AndriyM Yes, I need to select 2 values of 1 row that match my criteria (in my example 9 and 6)

Comment: If there was also a `(6,7)` row, should the result be either `(6,7)` or `(9,6)`?

Comment: @ypercube should be random, one between `(6,7)` and `(9,6)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, from the description, that you first need all rows with rows `(x,y)` where no other row `(y,x)` exists. Then select a random row from them:

```
SELECT r.leader, r.subscriber 
FROM relations AS r 
WHERE NOT EXISTS
      ( SELECT *
        FROM relations AS r2
        WHERE r.subscriber = r2.leader
          AND r.leader = r2.subscriber     -- or perhaps without this
      ) 
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1 ;
```

It would be useful to have two indexes, on `(leader, subscriber)` and on `(subscriber, leader)`. If the table is very big and performance is still not good, you may have to change how the random row is selected. The `ORDER BY RAND LIMIT 1` solution works ok in small tables but it's quite slow in big tables as it has to sort all the matching rows before it chooses one.

Comment: I cannot use it, this SQL takes too long time to execute

Comment: Can you edit the question and add the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE relations;`? How big is the table?

Comment: Ok, I just updated the question

Comment: I have updated the answer with useful indexes to add. Without any indexes on subscriber and leader, it's no wonder that the query is slow. Also, you don't need that `UNIQUE id` index. The PRIMARY KEY is identical.